# Animate a UIView with color changing Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, colors, gradient

I want to create a UIView that changes colors, I have an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbfF5ugqoHA, but I don't know to create that animation in Swift, I would appreciate a lot someone could tell me how. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use a CAGradientLayer and a CABasicAnimation.